# Getting yargs_1.default.options is not a function while using the yargs

Tags: typescript, nestjs, yargs

I am trying to use `yargs` library in my nestjs framework application, where few parameters i will be taking from command line args, if these parameters are not provided, I will be using the default one. Here is my `cli.ts` file.

```
import yargs from 'yargs';

const argv = yargs
  .options('awsRegion', {
    description: 'AWS Region (e.g. us-east-1, us-west-1)',
    alias: 'aws-region',
    type: 'string',
    default: 'aws-east-1',
  })
  .options('avbLeaderId', {
    description: 'leader id to be used for leader election',
    alias: 'avb-leader-id',
    type: 'string',
    default: 'avb-leader-id',
  })
  .parseSync();

export default argv;
```

When I am trying to access the Property in constructor of a DB class -

```
export class DbService {
  private client: DynamoDB;
 
  constructor() {

    this.client = new DynamoDB({
      region: argv.awsRegion,
    });
    
  }
```

I am getting following errors when i run using `npm run start:dev --aws-region=us-west-1` -

```
.options('awsRegion', {
   ^
TypeError: yargs_1.default.options is not a function
```

I have tried to go through documentation, but i am not gettting it.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure `yargs` is a default import? [From their docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs) it looks like it's a namespace import.`import * as yargs from 'yargs';`

Comment: This look like a problem using yargs default export from TypeScript. Are you generating CommonJS? Is tsconfig `esModuleInterop` false?